# How to pass name or ID of a button to Node using fetch

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I have a table that is filled with items from database and I'd like to have a button in every row that deletes that item from the database. My aproach was to give the button same id/name as the specific data it would be deleting but I don't know how to pass that id to node so it knows which exact item to delete. I am using fetch in js to make the POST with that button.

I'm using node with express, and I use ejs as my templating solution. My database is mongodb with mongoose.

This is the button, it is generated for every item in database and it has the same id as the item from database.

```
<button class="delete-button" id='<%= item._id %>'>X</button>
```

This is the fetch. Whole thing is in forEach to add the listener to each of the buttons

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    fetch('/delete', { method: 'POST' })
      .then(function (response) {
        if (response.ok) {
          console.log('Delete was recorded')
          return
        }
        throw new Error('Request failed.')
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  })
```

and this is app.post in node.

```
app.post('/delete', (req,res)=>{
    console.log("Deleted button has been clicked")
})
```

This works just fine, but I don't know how to pass the id to node.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use onclick and pass your value as a argument:

```
<button class="delete-button" onclick="deleting(<%= item._id %>)">X</button>
function deleting(value){
fetch('/delete', { method: 'POST', data: {buttonId: value} })
  .then(function (response) {
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log('Delete was recorded')
      return
    }
    throw new Error('Request failed.')
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

}

and on the server side:

```
app.post('/delete', (req,res)=>{
console.log("Deleted button has been clicked: "+ req.body.buttonId)
})
```

i guess you have body-parser installed?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but for some reason this.id is coming back undefined. even if I delete rest of the code and leave just the listener with callback logging the this.id.

Comment: yes i realized, thats why i edited the code. i used now `onclick` that works

Comment: Yes, now it works. Thank you. Another solution I found was just puting form around the button and getting to it through req.body, that way the value and name are passed with no issues, so just made it  that the value is the id.

Comment: @Esszed what about my answer? Did you try? By the way it is a rest convention to use delete method when a delete operation is made. Also in your delete api it is not good to have delete in the route url, if delete method is used, it is already clear that this is a delete operation.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I did not try it. I didn't want to use jquery because so far I would use it just for this operation in my whole app. Thank you about the DELETE information, though. I will definetly use it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the id to the delete url in javascript code like this:
(I also changed the method POST to DELETE because it is good to follow rest conventions)

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    fetch('/delete/'+this.id, { method: 'DELETE' })
      .then(function (response) {
        if (response.ok) {
          console.log('Delete was recorded')
          return
        }
        throw new Error('Request failed.')
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  })
```

And to get id in api side you can use req.params.id

```
app.delete('/delete/:id', (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.params.id);
    console.log("Deleted button has been clicked")
})
```

Comment: It does not work. Most likely again due to this.id coming back undefined.

Comment: @Esszed can you replace this.id with event.srcElement.id ?

Comment: If not, you can use inline event like in the other answer

Comment: It works, somewhat works. It is deleting stuff from database, but my redirect to home route does not work for some reason. So the deleted stuff dissapear after page reload

Comment: Maybe you should better to ask a new question about that issue

Comment: Well I'm gonna stick to my working solution right now and maybe I'll come back to it.

Answer (score 1):

in ejs file:
this goes inside the forEach loop

```
<form class="pull-right" action="/item/<%= item._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" value="Delete">
</form>
```

(you need to install the method-override library: npm install method-override --save)

here is the server side:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    methodOverride = require("method-override");

app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

app.delete("/item/:id", function(req, res){
    <item list in MongoDB>.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }else{
            res.redirect("/<index(ejs) page>");
        }
    });
});
```